# Continuous-piecewise-linear versus piecewise-linear

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, terminology

Some authors use the term "continuous piecewise-linear" where other authors use the shorter term "piecewise-linear" (with continuity tacit).

I'd be interested in people's thoughts about this nomenclatural issue. I'm sympathetic to the use of the term "cpl" in work of Kirillov and Berenstein (see e.g. http://math.uoregon.edu/~arkadiy/bk1.pdf), but I'm inclined to use the term "PL" in describing their work and applying their constructions, since the term seems more mainstream.

Then again, if lots of folks (especially those who work in algebraic combinatorics and representation theory) are moving in Kirillov and Berenstein's direction, maybe I should join them.

Comment: For the finite or locally finite complexes PL=CPL. So the difference might appear only in the weird part of our world and it requires more defs to see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "piecewise linear " means, linear (affine) on each member of some finite cover by  *closed* intervals,  then continuity is already there.

Comment: I neglected to mention that in this context the spaces are multidimensional. So where Pietro writes "intervals" we should think "simplices" (his point is valid in this broader setting).

Comment: sorry, I didn't realize it, and in the meanwhile I had some piecewise linear arcs my head.